# Не работает маршрутизация в ASP.NET MVC 5.0 при введение токена с точкой

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, маршрутизация

У меня есть контроллер `Labels` и его действие

```
public ActionResult ShowLabel(string label)
```

оно должно отображать метки.
Я хочу для этого действия прописать маршрут, прописываю вот так

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "ShowLabel",
   url: "Label/{label}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Labels", action = "ShowLabel" }
);
```

Всё работает с метками типа `C#`, `kkk` и другие без точки. А вот с меткой `ASP.NET` не работает и выдаёт ошибку 404. Так понял не работает из-за того что в имени тега есть точка, если другие теги с точкой вводить, тоже не работает.
Непонятно почему не работает, и как сделать так что бы и с точкой заработало.
Исполнение в действие вообще при таких метках не заходит.

Вот пример URLов

1. `http://localhost:58791/Label/тег3` - работает
2. `http://localhost:58791/Label/С#` - работает
3. `http://localhost:58791/Label/ASP.NET` - не работает

Причём если маршруты по умолчанию всё работает с любыми метками.
`http://localhost:58791/Labels/ShowLabel?label=ASP.NET` - работает если не делать маршрут `ShowLabel`.

Пробовал прописать ограничения:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "ShowLabel",
  url: "Label/{label}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Labels", action = "ShowLabel" },
  constraints: new { label = @"[.#\-+_$@\w]+" }
);
```

тот же результат.

Проверил, так же для `+` не работает в имени, а для `-` работает.

Попробовал так же в настройки добавить

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

`+` заработал, а `.` так и не работает.

Comment: [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, теперь работает.

Comment: Если сам нашёл решение стоит добавить его как ответ

Comment: @Grundy Это не я сам, это ты помог ))

Comment: Не :-) мне лень было переводить и проверять какой именно из ответов может помочь

Answer (score 1):

Вот такое помогло исправить ситуацию

Прописываем

```
<add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0"
     path="/Label/*"
     verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
     type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

в `system.webServer / handlers` в `web.config`

Взято из англоязычного ответа - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis

Правда такая запись работает только для контроллера `Label` что для меня является ограничением, а если надо для разных контроллеров и роутов, то придётся прописывать несколько раз. Но в моём проекте, это только для меток ( label ) и надо, так что этой записи хватает.

Comment: попробуй `path="*"`

Comment: я думал над этим, думаю что при таком статические файлы типа `my.css` и `my.js` будут тоже обрабатываться таким обработчиком. а так они по-идее должны обрабатываться IISом